# SELinux в Android (SEAndroid) - разрешающее правило не действует

Tags: android, безопасность, selinux

Устройство или ОС, прошивка: CyanogenMod 13.0 (Android 6.0.1)

Проблема:
При `SELinux=enforcing` приложение фонарика из CM-12.0 в режиме работы через `sysfs` крашится.

logcat:

```
01-04 20:36:35.315 3320 3320 D TorchRoot: Starting torch
01-04 20:36:35.332 3320 3320 W t.cactii.flash2: type=1400 audit(0.0:11): avc: denied { write } for name="brightness" dev="sysfs" ino=22032 scontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:torch_sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-04 20:36:35.343 3320 3320 D TorchDevice: setFlashMode 3
01-04 20:36:35.344 3320 3320 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
--------- beginning of crash
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: Process: net.cactii.flash2, PID: 3320
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't open flash device
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at net.cactii.flash2.FlashDevice.setFlashMode(FlashDevice.java:252)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at net.cactii.flash2.TorchService.handleMessage(TorchService.java:44)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/leds/torch-light/brightness: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:80)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at net.cactii.flash2.FlashDevice.setFlashMode(FlashDevice.java:228)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: ... 7 more
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
01-04 20:36:35.345 3320 3320 E AndroidRuntime: ... 11 more
01-04 20:36:35.349 840 1039 W ActivityManager: Force finishing activity net.cactii.flash2/.MainActivity
```

dmesg:

```
[  614.870153,1] type=1400 audit(1451928995.332:11): avc: denied { write } for pid=3320 comm="t.cactii.flash2" name="brightness" dev="sysfs" ino=22032 scontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:torch_sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

При `SELinux=permissive` приложение работает как должно (но в `dmesg` выдаётся аналогичное вышеприведенному предупреждение).

SELinux настроен так:

```
 $ grep torch device/jsr/d10f/sepolicy/*
 device/jsr/d10f/sepolicy/file_contexts:/sys/class/leds/torch-light/brightness        u:object_r:torch_sysfs:s0
 device/jsr/d10f/sepolicy/file_contexts:/sys/devices/qcom,camera-led-flash.([0-9])+/leds/torch-light/brightness u:object_r:torch_sysfs:s0
 device/jsr/d10f/sepolicy/file.te:type torch_sysfs,   fs_type, sysfs_type;
 device/jsr/d10f/sepolicy/platform_app.te:allow platform_app torch_sysfs:file write;
```

То есть:

1. На базе типа `sysfs_type` создан новый тип `torch_sysfs`
2. Файлам `torch-light/brightness` в `sysfs` присвоен контекст `u:object_r:torch_sysfs:s0`
3. Приложениям в домене `platform_app` разрешена запись в файлы с типом `torch_sysfs`

Почему разрешающее правило

```
 allow platform_app torch_sysfs:file write;
```

не действует?

Правило сгенерировано автоматически, командой:

```
 adb shell dmesg | audit2allow -p out/target/product/d10f/root/sepolicy


 #============= platform_app ==============
 allow platform_app torch_sysfs:file write;
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Я никогда не использовал такую систему защиты на телефоне, но немного работал с SELinux на самом Линуксе. Вот тут (https://russianblogs.com/article/41261316723/) я прочёл, что можно написать так, как вы верно написали (это пример с сайта):

```
allow radio sysfs:file write;
```

Попробуйте, если вы не пробовали, вместо `torch_sysfs` написать саму `sysfs`